# Adding boundary callback in pagedListAdaper

Tags: android

I am using rooms and live data to display data in adapter but I want to  download data from server when no old message are there in dB .I m wondering how to add setBoundryCallback in live data or pagedList

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already solved it but here is a possible solution for your problem:

1. Define a BoundaryCallback for the elements of your list (in this case I named it Object)

**MyBoundaryCallback.kt**

```
class MyBoundaryCallback(val context: Context): PagedList.BoundaryCallback<Object>(){

   // This is called when you reach the end of the list currently in the database.
   // You should make the call to the server here
   override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: Object) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Reached the end of the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }

   // This is called when no data is in the database
   override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {

      Toast.makeText(context, "0 items loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }
}
```

2. In your repository, or wherever you have defined your pagedlist, add setBoundary to your call

**Your repository.kt**

```
// somewhere in the code
val factory: DataSource.Factory<Int, Object> = myDao.getObjects()

val pagedListBuilder: LivePagedListBuilder<Int, Object> = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, Object>(factory, 10)
              .setBoundaryCallback(JokeBoundaryCallback(context!!))
              .build()
```